# Is the sequence of functions $f_n(x) = x^n$ uniformly convergent on $[0,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is the sequence of functions $f_n(x) = x^n$ uniformly convergent on $[0,1)$? I learned that $f_n(x)$ is not uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$ but what about on $[0,1)$? I think it does converge uniformly to $f(x)=0$ because I can always make $n$ big enough to fit $x^n$ to be within $\epsilon$ from $0$ for any $x$? Or is this not possible? I am not really sure on how to verify a sequence of functions is uniformly convergent on some domain.

Also, does uniformly convergent series imply that the series is also absolutely convergent?

Comment: For your last answer, no, uniform convergence of series does not imply absolute convergence or viceversa. The series $$F(x):=\sum_{k=0}^\infty f_k(x)$$ with $f_k(x):=\frac{(-1)^k}{k}$ converges uniformly in $\Bbb R$ but not absolutely.

Comment: Is $f_k(x) = \frac{-1^k}{k}$ still considered a function even though it doesn't depend on any $x$ for some domain? But doesn't your example follow the $M$-test, because $||f_k(x)||_{\sup} = \frac{-1^k}{k}$ because there is no $x$ where we can take $\sup$ of? Also, does this mean that uniformly convergence doesn't imply M-test?

Comment: Yes, the $f_k$ are constant functions in $\Bbb R$, but observe that the norms only can have non-negative values, hence $\|f_k\|_\infty=\frac1k\neq\frac{(-1)^k}k$ for odd $k$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **METHODOLOGY $1$:**

Note that for $x=1-1/n$, $x^n\to e^{-1}$.

Hence, $\displaystyle \sup_{x\in [0,1)} x^n\ne 0$ and the sequence does not converge to $0$ uniformly.

---

> **METHODOLOGY $2$:**

Alternatively, take $\epsilon=1/4$.  Then, for all $N\ge 1$ there exists a number $x=1-1/n$ and a number $n>N$ such that

$$x^n=\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n\ge \epsilon=\frac14$$

since $\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n$ increases monotonically.

Therefore, from the definition of the negation of uniform convergence we conclude that $x^n$ does not uniformly to $0$.

---

> **SHOWING UNFORM CONVERGENCE FOR $\displaystyle x\in [0,r], 0<r<1$**

We can show that $x^n$ converges uniformly on any compact subset of $[0,1)$.  Take $x\in [0,r]$ for $0<r<1$.  Then, we have for all $\epsilon>0$

$$x^n\le r^n<\epsilon$$

whenever $n>\max\left(1,\log(\epsilon)/\log(r)\right)$.

Comment: For $x=e^{-1/n}$ you have $x^n=e^{-1}$ and similarly for $x=\sqrt[1/n]{0.999}$ you have $x^n=0.999$

Comment: @Henry I don't understand the intent of the comment.  What are you implying?  Is it that $\sup_{0\le x<1}x^n=1$?

Comment: Since that means $x^n$ converges to some real number, it must be point-wise convergent?

Comment: @user3000482 For all $x\in [0,1)$, $\lim_{n\to \infty}x^n=0$.  But the convergence is not uniform.  Do you understand?

Comment: @Dr.MV I was only saying that you do not need "$\to e^{-1}$" since you can have "$=e^{-1}$" or equal to any other number between $0$ and $1$

Comment: I think the point is: if $f_n(x) \to 0$ uniformly on some set $S$ and $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence all of whose terms are in $S$, then $f_n(x_n) \to 0$.

Comment: @henry One need only show that the supremum is not $0$.  The hint should suffice, should it not?

Comment: @Dr.MV no, could you verify this is not uniformly convergent using the definition of the uniform convergence? I can't really understand how your example demonstrates this is not uniformly convergent, it seems your example shows $x^n$ must be uniformly convergent.

Comment: Yes, I'll edit to show the way forward.

Comment: But not really sure how you got $n>\max (1, \log(\epsilon)/\log(r))$... could you elaborate more on this part please?

Comment: Sure.  That is really there just to safeguard against cases for which $\epsilon\ge 1$.  Since we really only care about small $\epsilon$, this isn't an important case.

Comment: And you're quite welcome.  It's my pleasure.

Comment: Can I also prove this is not uniformly convergent using definition of uniformly cauchy?

Comment: That sounds like a good idea.  See if you can proceed.

Answer (score 3):

No, if the sequence uniformly converged to 0, then by applying the definition with $\epsilon := \frac{1}{2}$ there must exist some $N$ such that for all $n \ge N$ and $x \in [0, 1)$, $|f_n(x)| < \frac{1}{2}$.  But that gives a contradiction, since if you set $n := N$ and $x := 2^{-1/N}$, then $n \ge N$ and $x \in [0, 1)$ but $|f_n(x)| = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: That isn't the negation of uniform convergence.

Comment: Is this function uniformly convergent on any domain?

Comment: @user3000482 I've edited to address your last question.