# Show uniform convergence of sequence of functions $f_n(x)=x^n$ on $[0,0.9]$

Tags: calculus, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

Show uniform convergence of sequence of functions $f_n(x)=x^n$ on [0, 0.9].
There is a similar question for the interval [0, 1) (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191621/is-the-sequence-of-functions-f-nx-xn-uniformly-convergent-on-0-1). In this case it is not uniformly convergent. Now I need to show that it is uniformly convergent on [0, 0.9]. But I don't see the difference. Let's say if we have $x = 0.9^{1/n}$ then $x^n = 0.9$ and if we pick $\epsilon = 1/2$ then $x^n > \epsilon$. So where is my error?

Comment: What is your $x_n$?

Comment: We have $$
\left| {0 - x^n } \right| = \left| x \right|^n  \le 0.9^n  \Rightarrow \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \sup _{x \in \left[ {0,0.9} \right]} \left| {0 - x^n } \right| \le \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } 0.9^n  = 0.
$$ Thus, the sequence converges to the identically $0$ function on $\left[ {0,0.9} \right]$ uniformly.

Comment: @Gary sorry, edited.

Comment: Your choice does not work because $0.9^{1/n} >0.9$ so this $x$ is outside the interval.

Comment: Thanks, now I see it!